# Weird display of 'From' field in smtp email sent in python

Tags: python, email, smtp, smtplib

I am getting weird display of From field in smtp email.The display is like;

**from: test@gmail.com To: test@gmail.com, Subject: Message test@gmail.com
to:**

to field is blank but the another 'to' recipient, ie test1@gmail.com received the email successfully.
Below is my code.

```
import smtplib

def SendEmailScenario1():
    gmail_user = "test@gmail.com"
    gmail_password = '******'

    sent_from = gmail_user
    to = ["test1@gmail.com"]
    subject = 'Message'
    body = "Hi There! Done1"

    email_text = """\
    From: %s 
    To: %s 
    Subject: %s

    %s
    """ % (sent_from, ", ".join(to), subject, body)
    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
        server.ehlo()
        server.login(gmail_user, gmail_password)
        server.sendmail(sent_from, to, email_text)
        server.close()

        print ('Email sent!')
    except:
        print ('Something went wrong...')
def SendEmailScenario2():
    gmail_user = "test@gmail.com"
    gmail_password = '******'

    sent_from = gmail_user
    to = ["test1@gmail.com"]
    subject = 'Message'
    body = "Hi There! Done 2"

    email_text = """\
    From: %s 
    To: %s 
    Subject: %s

    %s
    """ % (sent_from, ", ".join(to), subject, body)
    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
        server.ehlo()
        server.login(gmail_user, gmail_password)
        server.sendmail(sent_from, to, email_text)
        server.close()

        print ('Email sent!')
    except:
        print ('Something went wrong...')
SendEmailScenario1()
SendEmailScenario2()
```

How to bring it to normal display without using **MIMEText, MIMEMultipart**

Answer (score 0):

RFC822 [specifies](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822.html#section-3.2) that a header should terminate with `'\r\n'`:

> field       =  field-name ":" [ field-body ] CRLF

Furthermore, the headers should be [separated from the body](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822.html#section-3.1) by an empty `'\r\n'`:

> [The body] is separated from the headers by a null line  (i.e.,  a
> line with nothing preceding the CRLF)

So the message should be constructed like this:

```
headers = "From: %s\r\nTo: %s\r\nSubject: %s\r\n\r\n"
email_text = headers + body
```

See also the example in the [smtplib docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtp-example).